# Git error "fatal: bad revision" when using git diff

Tags: git

I am trying to show changes between the origin of a certain folder and I would like it to show only the names of those that were added and modified using the following command but it is returning an error.

Command:

```
git diff --name-only --relative --diff-filter AM origin -- foldername/
```

Error:

```
fatal: bad revision 'origin'
```

Why did that suddenly happen? How can I resolve it?

Edit

using a different repo and 'origin/master' only returns different results

```
C:\gitprojects\samplefolder (master -> origin)
λ git diff --name-only --relative --diff-filter AM origin/master
readme.md

C:\gitprojects\samplefolder (master -> origin)
λ git diff --name-only --relative --diff-filter AM master origin/master
readme.md

C:\gitprojects\samplefolder (master -> origin)
λ git diff --name-only --relative --diff-filter AM origin
Properties/sample.properties
readme.md
```

Comment: My guess is that `origin` is a remote and not a revision. Maybe try something like `origin/master` instead? At least with `origin/master` instead of `origin` I don't get the error. I'm not sure what exactly you want to compare, though. Maybe you could add more detail about what exactly you expect the command to yield?

Comment: I also don't understand the error that is why I am asking. as for the expected result, I am expecting it to display the files that are different from any remote branch that I am in not only in master

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `man` page for `git diff` (run `man git-diff`).

In the **Description** section, you can identify the 4th variant for invoking `git diff` as the one you are using. The `man` page details its usage like this:

```
git diff [--options] <commit> [--] [<path>...]
    This form is to view the changes you have in your working tree relative to the named <commit>. You can
    use HEAD to compare it with the latest commit, or a branch name to compare with the tip of a different
    branch.
```

In your case, you are using the String `origin` as the `<commit>` (or revision) you want to compare your working tree to. This cannot work, because `origin` is not a revision/commit. That's what the error message is telling you.

`origin` is a "remote". A remote is just a reference to another *remote* clone of the repository and `git diff` cannot make comparisons between whole repositories, only between revisions/commits.

You can resolve this by specifying a commit you want to compare to. One example would be `origin/master`, meaning to compare to the tip of the `master` branch on the remote called `origin`. What commit to specify exactly depends on what you are trying to find out specifically.

Comment: using that returns different output, below is an example of working diff in a different repository

C:\gitprojects\samplefolder (master -> origin)
λ git diff --name-only --relative --diff-filter AM master origin/master
readme.md

C:\gitprojects\samplefolder (master -> origin)
λ git diff --name-only --relative --diff-filter AM origin
Properties/sample.properties
readme.md

Comment: Maybe you created a branch called `origin` in that repository, so that the branch called `origin` overshadows the remote called `origin` in that case.